# Need to speed up this loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm running an MCMC simulation in matlab and need to speed up the loop iterations, after profiling I found that the following loop is taking up the most time by far:

```
for i=1 : n
   u=0;
   for ii=0 : t-1
      if bitget(R(i),8-ii)==1
         u=bitset(u,ii+1+2*t);
      end
      if bitget(G(i),8-ii)==1
         u=bitset(u,ii+1+t);
      end
      if bitget(B(i),8-ii)==1
         u=bitset(u,ii+1);
      end
   end

   %u = Tcb(i)*Tcr(i);   
   p(1+u) = p(1+u) + 1; %kernel(X(i)*X(i)+Y(i)*Y(i));
end
```

It is a part of an algorithm to obtain the colour distribution of an image.
Here are the profile results:

[image: profile results]

Comment: What is the value of `t`?  Is this your data bitsize (*eg* 8)?

Answer (score 1):

You can save some time by defining 8-ii and ii+1 as variables at the beginning of your loop, thereby reducing repeated calculations.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 8-bit values and you are reversing the bits in each of the red, green and blue channels, then packing them into a 24-bit value.

Read the Bit Twiddling Hacks page entry *Reverse the bits in a byte with 7 operations*:

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseByteWith32Bits

These operations are surely faster than `bitget` and `bitset`.  MatLab provides shifting and bitwise-and.

You can make an anonymous function that does the reversal, then shift and pack the results with bitwise-or.

Answer (score 1):

Without more knowledge I can only prevent double calculations as @Theoretical described as well as some double lookups.

```
for i=1 : n
   u=0;
   ri = R(i);
   gi = G(i);
   ui = U(i);
   for ii=0 : t-1
      pos = 8 - ii;
      if bitget(ri,pos)
         u=bitset(u,ii+1+2*t);
      end
      if bitget(gi,pos)
         u=bitset(u,ii+1+t);
      end
      if bitget(ui,pos)
         u=bitset(u,ii+1);
      end
   end

   %u = Tcb(i)*Tcr(i);   
   p(1+u) = p(1+u) + 1; %kernel(X(i)*X(i)+Y(i)*Y(i));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `R`, `G` and `B` are marices of type `uint8`. How about

```
% flip bytes function   
flip2dec = @( x ) bin2dec( char( '0' + x(8:-1:1) ) );
flip = @( x ) flip2dec( bitget( x, 1:8 ) );
% flip all at once
fR = arrayfun( flip, R );
fG = arrayfun( flip, G );
fB = arrayfun( flip, B );

u = bitshift( uint32(fR), 16 ) + bitshift( uint32(fG), 8 ) + fB;

p = accumarray( double(u(1:n)) +1, 1 ); % up to transposing of inputs
```